# Find a minimum-weight perfect 2-matching

Tags: matching

How would one find a minimum-weight perfect 2-matching of a general graph? Is it possible to use standard matching techniques like Blossom V?

A minimum-weight perfect 2-matching of a graph G is a subgraph M of minimal total edge weight, such that each vertex in G is incident by exactly 2 edges from M.

Answer (score 1):

From an answer to my other question it turns out that one can convert this problem to standard matching.

[Find a minimum-weight perfect b-matching, where b is even](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104044/find-a-minimum-weight-perfect-b-matching-where-b-is-even)

I still wonder whether this would give the most efficient approach?