# Find a minimum-weight perfect b-matching, where b is even

Tags: matching

How would one find a minimum-weight perfect b-matching of a general graph, where the number of edges incident on each vertex is a positive even number not greater than b?

A minimum-weight perfect b-matching of a graph G is a subgraph M of minimal total edge weight, such that each vertex in G is incident by exactly b edges from M.

Comment: What is a perfect $b$-matching? Please make your question self-contained.

Comment: added definition of a perfect b-matching. Note that I actually want a perfect b-matching where b is also even and positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subgraph in which each vertex has degree exactly $b$ is known as a *$b$-factor*. You are asking for something similar (but not identical) to the minimum weight $b$-factor.

Tutte showed how to reduce minimum weight $b$-factor to minimum weight perfect matching in his paper [A short proof of the factor theorem for finite graphs](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/matching/Tutte-short-proof-of-factor-theorem.pdf).

We will split each vertex $v$ of degree $d(v)$ into $2d(v) - b$ vertices: $v_1,\ldots,v_{d(v)},v'_1,\ldots,v'_{d(v)-b}$ (we can assume that $d(v) \geq b$, since otherwise the graph has no $b$-factor). We lift each edge $(x,y)$ to an edge $(x_i,y_j)$ of the same weight in such a way that each $x_i$ and $y_j$ participates in exactly one such edge. We furthermore connect each $v_i$ to each $v'_j$ with a zero-weight edge, for all $i \in [d(v)]$ and $j \in [d(v)-b]$.

Each $b$-factor of the original graph corresponds to a matching in the new graph of the same weight. Indeed, lift the $b$-factor to the new graph, and for each vertex $v$, add an arbitrary matching between $v'_1,\ldots,v'_{d(v)-b}$ and the $d(v)-b$ new vertices corresponding to "unused ports".

Conversely, we can convert every matching in the new graph to a $b$-factor of the same weight in the original graph by undoing this construction.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the algorithm I had in mind. It’s amazing that Tutte found it so long ago. I also wanted to force b to be even and positive. For this to work we can create 4d(v)-b vertices with 2d(v)-b of them ports. We also need to connect pairs of ports together.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean – you get to choose $b$.

Comment: So you choose an even b. Now I want every vertex to be incident by an even number of edges in the matching less or equal to b. If b is 6 then the allowed number of incident edges is 2, 4 or 6. 5 edges would not be allowed.

Comment: Ah – now I see what you mean.